# since Integer.MAX_VALUE+1==Integer.MIN_VALUE+1, how long will this loop run(sounds like a dumb question but its not)?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int x=0 ; x != 0 ; x++) {}
```

(A) will the loop run 4 billion times because x will start at 0 then approach max value (2^31-1)

(B) will the loop run 2 billion times because x will approach max value then an error will appear

(C) will it run forever because x will approach infinity

Comment: Pretty sure the condition is evaluated first and it won’t run at all. Why don’t you test it out?

Comment: yeah I fixed that, sorry it was supposed to be x=1

Comment: Your correction has completely changed the question.  That's not allowed!  It invalidates the previous Answers.  Don't do it.

Comment: (And you don't need to @talex's answer already gives the answer to the question that you meant to ask.)

Comment: yeah sorry, I realized I wrote the question wrong, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't loop at all.

You initialize `x = 0` and then check `x != 0`. So loop will ends immediately.

If you initialize `x = 1` then you get "2^32-1" iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The loop body will run exactly zero times.  On the first iteration, `x != 0` will be false.

In the general case of a `for` loop:

```
for (<initializations>; <condition>; <post> ) {
    <body>
}
```

the execution sequence is:

1. `<initializations>`
2. `if <condition> then end`
3. `<body>`
4. `<post>`
5. `go to 2.`

---

> (A) will the loop run 4 billion times because x will start at 0 then approach max value (2^31-1)

Nope.  The arithmetic is wrong. 2^31-1 is not 4 billion.  It is a bit over 2 billion.

> (B) will the loop run 2 billion times because x will approach max value then an error will appear.

Nope.  Integer overflow in Java doesn't raise an error / exception.

> (C) will it run forever because x will approach infinity

Nope.  It wouldn't approach infinity.  An `int` value cannot be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: oops it was supposed to be 1, sorry i shoukd have reviewed